# Client server communication without using the GWT RPC

Tags: gwt, rpc, json-rpc

I would like to pass data between client and the server without using the GWT RPC.
I need to send the JSON data and get back the response. 
How can I achieve this wihtout using GWT RPC ? Please provide with the example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the official Tutorial from Google:
[Retrieving JSON Data](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON.html)